# How to install/use Python ChatBot?

Tags: python, pip

I'm getting the following error when attempting to import "ChatBot":

```
>>> from chatterbot import ChatBot
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chatterbot/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/chatterbot/chatterbot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage import StorageAdapter
ImportError: No module named storage
>>>
```

The documentation https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot states to simply run:

```
pip install chatterbot
```

I did that, also tried --user. Same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChatterBot [requires Python 3.4+](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/blob/2ead83e6a320f378a8d543f2486694f0f0b759a5/setup.py#L57).

Comment: Thanks, but why do the instructions then say to simply use pip install?

Comment: Because this a generic type of instructions; if you only have Python 3.4 installed the name of the script is `pip`; if you use virtualenv the name of the script is `pip`.

Comment: it is pip in both cases?

Comment: It's always `pip`, especially in docs. You distinguish `pip2` and `pip3` when you have 2 different Python versions, 2.7 and 3+. You can further subdivide the list using `pip2.7`, `pip3.4`, `pip3.5`, etc. if you have many different Python versions (I test my libraries with 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 and PyPy, 32- and 64-bit versions).